# My Tab component is not showing in my browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, tabs

This is my Tab component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Tab, Tabs, Grid, Cell,Card,CardTitle, CardActions, CardText, CardMenu, Button, IconButton} from 'react-mdl'


class Projects extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={ activeTab:0 };
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="category-tabs">
              <Tabs activeTab={this.state.activeTab} onChange={(tabId) => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId })} ripple>
                    <Tab>React</Tab>
                    <Tab>GitHub</Tab>
                    <Tab>Linkdln</Tab>
              </Tabs>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

After linking together my project page was blank and i checked the console, there was no errors.
Other page are showing i don't know the reason why that is not showing

Comment: I can't see you exporting your Projects component.

Comment: I did, I cut that place off

Comment: Can you post the component where you have used this component?

Comment: https://tleunen.github.io/react-mdl/components/tabs/

Comment: the link where i got the component